# How can I pass "start date" and "end date" as command line arguments in Python

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to transfer data from one table to another using Python based on date range.

```
import anprint
import os
import sys
import re
import datetime
from mydb import cursor

try:
    cam_name = sys.argv[1]
    rec_date = sys.argv[2]
except:
    print "Usage: %s cam_name date " % sys.argv[0]
    sys.exit(1)

dbObj = anprint.ExcelDb()

# Get a list of the plates...
tablename = "customer_1.%s_anpr_vega" % cam_name
sql = """SELECT plate, datetime, id FROM %s WHERE DATE(datetime)="%s" """ % (tablename, rec_date)
cursor.execute(sql)
retval = cursor.fetchall()
for values in retval:
    print values
    (vrm, vrm_datetime, record_id) = values
    dbObj.reconcile_plate(cam_name, vrm, vrm_datetime, record_id)
```

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with [tag:php] - please, specify what and where do you want to pass

Comment: need to pass start date and end date in command line.

Comment: Looks like python, edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It bad paractice:

```
sql = """SELECT plate, datetime, id FROM %s WHERE DATE(datetime)="%s" """ % (tablename, rec_date)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Do below:

```
sql = """SELECT plate, datetime, id FROM %s WHERE DATE(datetime)=?""" % tablename
cursor.execute(sql, [rec_date])
```

2) It's simple and not good solution to use `sys.argv[n]` for get command line arguments like `cam_name = sys.argv[1]`. Good way is to use [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) for assign command line arguments to script.

3) It's good practice use [`between`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) operator in sql like this:

```
sql = "SELECT plate, datetime, id FROM " +tablename+ " WHERE datetime between ? and ?"
    cursor.execute(sql, [start_date, end_date])
```

Furthermore [read it](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) for understanding parameters style SQL query.

Comment: thanks Michael I need the start date and end date in command line  `sql = """SELECT plate, datetime, id FROM %s WHERE date(datetime)>'2013-02-02' and date(datetime) <'2013-02-30'and  DATE(datetime)=?""" % tablename
cursor.execute(sql, [rec_date])`

Comment: I got it but small doubt do i need to pass date time in place of ? or just leave it as start_date and end_date `sql = "SELECT plate, datetime, id FROM " +tablename+ " WHERE datetime between "2013-03-29" and "2013-03-31""
    cursor.execute(sql, [start_date, end_date])'

Comment: @preethi You can use only date for `start_date` and  `end_date`. In this case RDBMS set time as `00:00:00`. For my time standard date `05.12.2013` will represent as `05.12.2013 00:00:00`. Also you can set `start_date` and  `end_date` as `05.12.2013 00:00:00`

Comment: @preethi, it wrong code `... between "2013-03-29" and "2013-03-31"" cursor.execute(sql, [start_date, end_date])`. You can use `... between '2013-03-29' and '2013-03-31'" cursor.execute(sql)` or `... between ? and ?"; cursor.execute(sql, [start_date, end_date])`. In last case DB driver has to adjust to SQL syntax.

Comment: Hi Michael I am doing something wrong can you please  look at my code and please correct me .. `
`from mydb import cursor
try:
    cam_name = sys.argv[1]
    rec_date = sys.argv[2] end_date = sys.argv[3]
except:
    print "Usage: %s cam_name date  date" % sys.argv[0]
    bObj = anprint.ExcelDb()
# Get a list of the plates...
tablename = "customer_1.%s_anpr_vega" % cam_name
sql = """SELECT plate, datetime, id FROM %s WHERE  Date(datetime) < '2013-03-28' and date(datetime) > '2013-03-31' and DATE(datetime)="%s" """ % (tablename, rec_date)
cursor.execute(sql)
retval = cursor.fetchall()`
`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42593/discussion-between-michael-kazarian-and-preethi)

Comment: Replace it:
sql = """SELECT plate, datetime, id FROM %s WHERE datetime between'2013-03-28' and '2013-03-31' """ % tablename

Comment: SOLVED THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR HELP >> MICHEAL YOU ARE A STAR>>>>>